# how do I give out free review copies of my paid android app?

Tags: android, review

With the iPhone, Apple has a system of free codes you can send to reviewers so they can install the app for free.  Is there a way to do this with paid Android apps?

Comment: I asked a related question recently: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2014633/how-can-you-make-a-review-copy-of-an-android-app

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Android Market doesn't make any provision for this currently.

There was a very similar question recently asking about how best to implement checks that would enable the distribution of review copies:
[How can you make a review copy of an Android app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2014633/how-can-you-make-a-review-copy-of-an-android-app/2014714#2014714)